# How to add my own GRASS algorithms to Processing?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I need to use algorithm r.bioclimatic from GRASS in QGIS but I see that this algorithm don't exist in Processing Toolbox. A search a way of add this algorithm to Processing and in GRASS and Sextante page if find this way:

HOWTO adding own GRASS algorithms to Sextante (simply by adding a new description file)

I create a description file according to the rules but now I don't know how to run and if this will run in GRASS.

The first parameters of r.bioclimatic (tmin, tmax....) are columns of tables? I don't know which type of input I have.

Comment: New and related development: gis.stackexchange.com/a/319333/5256

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[r.bioclim](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.bioclim.html) (I suppose, because r.bioclimatic don't exist), is an GRASS GIS 7 addon

If you want to create or modify an algorithm, read the file `../processing/algs/grass7/grass7.txt` that begins with "*A short guide for creating and editing GRASS GIS 7 algorithms*"

But, how do these commands work ?

- to use the GRASS7 commands in `processing`,you need to first specify the GRASS GIS installation (in Processing/options) and `processing` will look for scripts that are in the folders `bin` and `scripts` of your GRASS installation (GISBASE environment variable) in the script `../processing/algs/grass7/Grass7AlgorithmProvider.py`
- the script is executed with the Python module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) in the `../processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Utils.py` script

The big problem is that the addons are not installed in these folders (GRASS_ADDON_PATH environment variable) therefore you can simply use them with `processing`

Conclusion ? QGIS is not GRASS GIS and if you want to use a "specialized" algorithm (addon), use GRASS GIS

Answer (score 2):

To complete the Gene's answer consider that you can install addons at system level when installing it with g.extension using the "-s" option. In this way the algorithm is found out by processing.

So you can keep using GRASS inside QGIS!