# How can I use GRASS r.catchment in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'd like to use the [r.catchment](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.catchment.html) tool from GRASS within QGIS. It looks like this is a tool that hasn't yet been developed into a processing tool under the GRASS commands. Is there some other way to load GRASS tools within QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, beside GRASS processing tools you can use **GRASS 7 plugin** (available from QGIS 2.12) which integrates GRASS Environment directly to QGIS. You have to activate it in menu `Plugins --> Manage and Install Plugins ...`, then GRASS menu appears in `Plugins` menu.

To use this approach you have to be familiar with GRASS and how it works with data (see [QGIS documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html)). For hydrology analysis you can also use a SAGA tools from processing toolbox.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'd prefer not to have to immerse myself in the details of how GRASS does things but it looks like I have no choice. Thanks for pointing me to the the plugin.

Comment: ... he wrote: "which integrates GRASS Environment directly..."  - sounds rather harmless :-)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid some frustration:

I am afraid, the answer is you currently cannot use r.catchment out of the box from QGIS, because r.catchment is an AddOn and neither Processing nor the QGIS-GRASS-plugin allow for using AddOns.

The only possibility I know of would be, if you add that module to the QGIS-GRASS-plugin yourself. That means: copy the script to the plugin source [1](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/src/plugins/grass/scripts), add a module description (.qgm-file) for it to [2](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/src/plugins/grass/modules) and activate it in the module tree [3](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/plugins/grass/modules/default.qgc). You can do that in your local installation, and do not have to compile anything. Just reload the modules when you are done...

If you need r.catchment, and esp. if you run hydrological analysis on a regular basis, I would simply dive into GRASS!

Please have a look at:

[Adding_New_Tools_to_the_GRASS_Toolbox](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Adding_New_Tools_to_the_GRASS_Toolbox)

[how-to-add-my-own-grass-algorithms-to-processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150100/how-to-add-my-own-grass-algorithms-to-processing)