# Adding 3rd party grass script into qgis processing toolbox on Mac?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, mac, grass-7.0, toolbox

I am trying to integrate this script http://www.mergili.at/randomwalk.php into QGIS on Mac, but I am having a few problems.

I have already seen [How to add my own GRASS algorithms to Processing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150100/how-to-add-my-own-grass-algorithms-to-processing/150142#150142)

But the answer is not really useful, as that is not dealing with my problem on Mac.

I have also seen this post in the OSGeo mailinglist, and in fact the problem seems similar:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Adding-grass-commands-to-the-processing-toolbox-td5196428.html

However, as the author says in the second email, he did find a solution for mac but not for windows.

Having considered all that, my question is:

how do you install an external script like randomwalk on QGIS for mac?

In particular, what are the specific steps one has to follow?

1) on Mac, in which folder should I copy the script I want to integrate?
Somewhere in the application folder? somewhere in the user/.qgis2/ folder?
Note that I use a version of QGIS installed from binary, and I use GRASS 7, the version integrated in the app folder.

2) on Mac, where should I put the .txt description file?
In /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/description/ or somewhere else?

3) on Mac, where should I put the html file of the algoritm?

4) the zip file of the algoritm contains the following files:

r.randomwalk.cdf.r

r.randomwalk.main.c

r.randomwalk.map.r

r.randomwalk.mult.py

r.randomwalk.multval.r

r.randomwalk.py

r.randomwalk.roc.r

which one should I put where in QGIS on mac? Especially which one should I put in the folder of 1) here above?

Comment: Take the tour please. For example you should only have one question per post, you have at least five.

Comment: They are obviously related subquestions for a single problem: if you don't like them being numbered, you can summirize them into one:
"how do you install an external script like randomwalk on QGIS for mac?"

If you have an answer for this, or for one of the above, you should have an answer for all of them.

Comment: I am sorry, but how can a question that asks how to add *one* specific script to QGIS on *one* specific OS be closed because "too broad"?

I pointed out the different steps I am not clear about because the only other question on this topic I have found has jsut a very general and vague answer, which yes it is too broad..

Comment: Dear Bera, I did take the tour. And I did realize that there is another question which is broadly dealing with a similar issue, but it is not really answering the specific *points* that I am asking here.
If you really think it is broad, and you could suggest an edit, or your could try to answer it (maybe..?), but what is the point of closing it?

Comment: I repeat, they are not "multiple *distinct* questions". They are clarifications about *one single* question about *one single* algorithm for *one single* OS